# nested comment system in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a comments table which has following columns

**id,answer_id,user_id,parent_id**

I am trying to make a nested comment system, where a user can reply to parent comment and also one can reply to child comment.

I just want to make two level(not exactly nested)

```
 $comments = DB::table('comments')
                        ->join('answers', 'answers.id' , '=', 'comments.answer_id')
                        ->join('users' , 'users.id' , '=', 'comments.user_id')
                        ->where('answers.id', '=' , $answer_id)
                        ->where('parent_id', '0')
                        ->select('comments.comment as comment',
                                'comments.id as comment_id',
                                'comments.created_at as created_at',
                                'comments.parent_id as parent_id',
                                'users.first_name as first_name',
                                'users.last_name as last_name',
                                // 'answers.aanswer as answer',
                                'answers.id as ans_id')

                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                        ->get();
```

This is query which is fetching parent comments of every answers

i was trying like this to fetch child and sub child comments

```
 foreach ($comments as $comment) {

            echo $comment->comment_id.$comment->comment.'<br>';
            child_comment($comment->comment_id);
           }
```

This is function that i am calling inside foreach loop to append child and subchild comment but it didn't help

```
public function child_comment($pid){
        $child_comments = Comment::where('id', $pid)
                                ->where('parent_id', '!=','0')
                                // ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                                ->select('comment')
                                ->get();
                               foreach($child_comments as $child_comment){
                                    echo $child_comment->comment.'<br>';
                               }     


           }
```

Someone suggested to make another table which will have child and sub child comments but i wanted to do everything just in one table, Please can someone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i would suggest using Eloquent (it would do most of the job itself).

Without testing your solution, i think the problem is this line:

`child_comment($comment->parent_id);`

If i get this correct you should pass the comments ID and not the parent_id into this function to get the child comments.

When you pass in the parent_id your query will always return nothing because you check if the comments parent_id is 0. The "first level" comment will never have a parent_id.